# how to call java object in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

I have user defined jar file which has .class files **Ex: abc.jar.**

I want to use those class files in the HTML file via JavaScript. I don't want to use applet calls.

Can some one please help out me on this?

Comment: When will people finally understand that Java != JavaScript...

Comment: Java has **no** relation to JavaScript. You cannot use Java objects in JavaScript.

Comment: *"I don't want to use applet calls."*  Applets, or JS calls to Java on the server, are the only way to achieve it.  You can't always get what you want..

Comment: Java is to JavaScript what Car is to Carpet.

Comment: You can't do it. You would need to create a server, make your javascript talk to the server via AJAX or some other means, process the requests against the user file, wrap the results and push them back out over the server. You could also look into using JSP, running on a server, to produce the views.

Comment: Java and Javascript are very different from each other. Java has static typing; JavaScript's typing is dynamic. JavaScript is weakly typed while Java is more strongly typed. Java is loaded from compiled bytecode; JavaScript is loaded as human-readable source code. Java's objects are class-based; JavaScript's are prototype-based. JavaScript also has many functional features based on the Scheme language. Because of these differences there is no way, no way these languages could work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run some java code(In server) and get the response in your javascript(in client). You can use Ajax in jquery.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Remember this is for java (advance) programming.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement `DWR` in your project

for step by step tutorial refer- 
 http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/getting-started.html

Please explain your requirement for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I am not using any server side programming.   Ex : Abc.jar has Math.class , the Class contains add, mul,div,sub Operations.  I want to use those operation on my javascrpt.

Comment: If you want to use your java `.class` files, you have to make it a web application

Comment: @SrikanthChilukuri: You can't do that - you simply can't load classes from Java in Javascript. Period. JavaScript is unrelated to Java, it's a completely different language which was created by a completely different company. It share's the word "Java" because some of the naming conventions were taken from Java, nothing more. There is no compatibility whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Java objects in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The ECMA standard doesn't cover communication with Java, thus you can't use Java objects in JavaScript - don't be confused by the name, although they share the word "Java", both languages have a completely different syntax and are completely different languages (Java is compiled to bytecode which is run on a virtual machine, JavaScript is a script language that is interpreted).

Answer (score 1):

Java objects **CANNOT** be used in JavaScript. Period.